# How can I install the MySQL client?

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql server and want to install the mysql client using following code:

```
apt-get install mysql-client
```

but I got following error message:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

It looks like the file locked and permission, if it is the case, it does not ask me for a password.

Your help and information is great appreciated.

Regards,

Inung

Comment: Why didn't you use software center?

Comment: it works now, after I reboot the computer, for some reason, computer locked the file to install client,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `sudo` to run `apt-get`.  You can install the mysql client with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```